# Javascript function calls not working in IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript, function, audio, call

When I call the following functions nothing happens, when I use them in in-line js they working fine. Am I doing something wrong?

```
 <script>

    var muted = false;
    function playAudio(var audioFile)
    {
        var audio = document.getElementElementId(audioFile);
        audio.play();
    }
    function toggleMute(var audioFile)
    {
        var audio = document.getElementById(audioFile)
        if(muted)
        {
            audio.play();
        }
        else
        {
            muted = !muted;
            audio.pause();
        }
    }
</script>
```

and the calls:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleMute('bg_music')">mute</button>
```

however when I use in-line JS like below it works fine.

```
<area shape="poly" coords="232,110,246,119,233,141,219,134,232,110
onclick="document.getElementById('ipod').play()">
```

Am I doing something wrong when I call these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in how you're calling the functions, but in how you're declaring them. You don't need to include the `var` keyword in a parameter list.

Try this:

```
function playAudio(audioFile)
{
    ...
}

function toggleMute(audioFile)
{
    ...
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [MDN: Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to remember that. It didn't have any effect though

Comment: @Callum.W Do you see any errors in the console? You may have other syntax problems in the page that's preventing your scripts from compiling correctly. (I don't see any here)

Comment: ah, yes, I just checked and I'm getting this: Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleMute is not defined

DISREGARD LAST

I had left the first var in there, I have been looking at the screen for too damn long. Thanks for your help